# Monacaアプリで、ファイルからアプリを起動できるようにする

Tags: ios, monaca

メールなどで設定ファイルを送り、そのファイルをタップしたときに表示される「開くアプリの選択」画面から当アプリを選択し、ファイルを読み込むような方法が出来たらと思うのですが、そのような仕組みをMonacaアプリで構築することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 対応するOSはどれでしょうか？

Comment: iPadでの使用を想定していますので、iosになりますが、androidでも可能な方法があればなおいいと思っています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。タグを追加しました。（そしてiOSのこのあたりは詳しくないので回答できない。。。

Comment: この機能を使いたいのは、複数のアプリユーザーが、同じ設定を用いるために、設定ファイルをメールなどで配れたら、と思ったからでした。
別の手法があれば、ヒントをいただけると幸いです。

Comment: なるほど。設定データを配布するなどであればKii Cloud(ステマ)のようなBaaSを使うという手があります